# Sub Report Content is not showing on the Main Report in Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

In Jasper Main Report, i am created one sub report in summary band, i customized  sub report as per my requirements, when i previewing my sub report its showing data as i am expected format. But, when i previewing the main report it's return back to the designer, preview is not showing then i just moved the sub report from details band into Summary band, now the main report previewing but, it's not showing the sub report content.

Can anyone guide me to achieve the result.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: post your main report and sub report.

Comment: Make sure you are sending required parameters to sub-report from main report

Answer (score 0):

Is your main report is empty? try checking the properties to display all section except details section when no data is available. If you are using different data source for sub report then there is a chance sub report will not get displayed. So make sure your connection parameters for your sub report are correct.if your main report and sub report are using same connection choose Report connection parameter for sub report connection to use main report connection settings.

Comment: Everything is perfect only